# unrecognized time zone

Tags: r, linux, timezone, lubridate, tzdata

With a recent update on Ubuntu (23.10 mantic), my R no longer recognizes `"US/Eastern"`.

```r
sessionInfo()
# R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 23.10
# Matrix products: default
# BLAS:   /opt/R/4.3.2/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so 
# LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3;  LAPACK version 3.11.0
# locale:
#  [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
#  [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C           LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   
# time zone: America/New_York
# tzcode source: system (glibc)
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# other attached packages:
# [1] r2_0.10.0
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#  [1] compiler_4.3.2  clipr_0.8.0     fastmap_1.1.1   cli_3.6.2       tools_4.3.2     htmltools_0.5.7 rmarkdown_2.25  knitr_1.45      xfun_0.41      
# [10] digest_0.6.34   rlang_1.1.3     evaluate_0.23  

lubridate::with_tz(Sys.time(), tzone = "US/Eastern")
# Warning in with_tz.default(Sys.time(), tzone = "US/Eastern") :
#   Unrecognized time zone 'US/Eastern'
# [1] "2024-03-18 13:49:56"
```

On a similarly-configured (R-wise) 22.04 jammy system, however, it works just fine.

```r
sessionInfo()
# R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
# Matrix products: default
# BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
# LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so;  LAPACK version 3.10.0
# locale:
#  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
# time zone: Etc/UTC
# tzcode source: system (glibc)
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] compiler_4.3.2

lubridate::with_tz(Sys.time(), tzone = "US/Eastern")
# [1] "2024-03-18 09:49:19 EDT"
```

Why does a normally-recognized TZ become unusable?

---

This is true on the OS itself, not just in R:

```bash
$ TZ="America/New_York" date
Mon Mar 18 10:22:03 AM EDT 2024
$ TZ="US/Eastern" date
Mon Mar 18 02:22:07 PM  2024
```

(notice the missing TZ in the second output)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The debate over the use of "Country/Region" (e.g. `"US/Eastern"`) as opposed to "Continent/City" (`"America/New_York"`) is not new. There is less ambiguity in the latter, where geopolitical forces can change the meaning of the former. So far (and still, afaict), the stance has been to maintain backward compatibility.

However, when `tzdata` 2024 was released, on Ubuntu 23.10 the package (`2024a-0ubuntu0.23.10`) does not include the `US/` symlinks; the same package on Ubuntu 22.04 *does* contain the links (`2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04`)

Based on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/2058249, the proper (and intended) fix is to install the `tzdata-legacy` linux package (and then restart R).

My first solution/hack is below, written before I learned about the `tzdata-legacy` package (above). The hack was easy enough given that I have root access to the underlying filesystem. Unless you are loath to installing the extra package for some reason, you should likely go with `tzdata-legacy` instead. (These symlinks are the few that I wanted, the `tzdata-legacy` package has another 675 symlinks/files. The package split affects a lot more than just `US/*`, after all.)

```bash
mkdir /usr/share/zoneinfo/US
cd /usr/share/zoneinfo/US
ln -s ../America/Anchorage Alaska
ln -s ../America/Adak Aleutian
ln -s ../America/Phoenix Arizona
ln -s ../America/Chicago Central
ln -s ../America/New_York Eastern
ln -s ../America/Indiana/Indianapolis East-Indiana
ln -s ../Pacific/Honolulu Hawaii
ln -s ../America/Indiana/Knox Indiana-Starke
ln -s ../America/Detroit Michigan
ln -s ../America/Denver Mountain
ln -s ../America/Los_Angeles Pacific
ln -s ../Pacific/Pago_Pago Samoa
```

After that, restart R ("should not" require reinstalling `lubridate` or `timechange` R packages) and it should then work. (I don't use RStudio, but you may need to restart that as well ... feedback on this is welcome.)

```r
lubridate::with_tz(Sys.time(), tzone = "US/Eastern")
# [1] "2024-03-18 09:55:08 EDT"
```

And in a shell (outside of R) as well:

```r
$ TZ="US/Eastern" date
Mon Mar 18 10:23:11 AM EDT 2024
```

Comment: Wow.  Good find!  Not sure if I agree with their intentions here though.  Will be interesting to follow.

Comment: I don't think installing `tzdata-legacy` is not best, sorry, what have you that idea? This answer spiraled as I found more information, is there something I can word better @DidierL?

Comment: I see your point, thanks @DidierL. As for the hack, it was the first draft before I found the underlying reasons.

Comment: @SamR ... perhaps it isn't that necessary, but part of my journey to the finish was learning that `US/Eastern` has, for quite some time, been defined solely as a symlink to `America/New_York`. I have always thought that `US/Eastern` (and all other `US/*` and `Pacific/*` and similar non-city definitions) were all first-class citizens, so to speak, in the tzdata realm, when in fact they are simply symlinks. So while you're right, the hack is not required, I think I'll keep it as a small lesson and reminder. (I hope nobody downvotes me for that, but to each their own :-)