# How do I fix my timezone issues on my R Shiny App? Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'

Tags: r, timezone, lubridate, posixct

I have an R Shiny application that is giving me many timezone errors that cause the app to be delayed on startup. The errors say:

```
Warning in strptime(.enclose(x), .enclose(fmt), tz) : unknown timezone 'GMT+5'
Warning in as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone 'GMT+5'
Warning in as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone 'GMT+5'
Warning in as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone 'GMT+5'
Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'GMT+5'
Warning in with_tz.default(x, tz) : Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'
Warning in with_tz.default(x, tz) : Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'
Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'GMT+5'
Warning in with_tz.default(x, tz) : Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'
Warning in with_tz.default(x, tz) : Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'
Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'GMT+5'
Warning in with_tz.default(x, tz) : Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'
Warning in with_tz.default(x, tz) : Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'
Warning in strptime(.enclose(x), .enclose(fmt), tz) : unknown timezone 'GMT+5'....repeat
```

I also deploy this application to the web where it also throws these errors:

```
Warning in with_tz.default(x, tz) : Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'
Warning in with_tz.default(x, tz) : Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'
Warning in with_tz.default(x, tz) : Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'
Warning in with_tz.default(x, tz) : Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'...repeat
```

Here is a snippet of my code, where I set the timezone of the data like this:

```
 data$x <- parse_date_time(data$x, orders = c("dmy HM", "dmy H", "dmY HM", "dmY"), tz="GMT+5")
 data2$x <- parse_date_time(data2$x, orders = c("dmy HM", "dmy H", "dmY HM", "dmY"), tz="GMT+5")
```

I'm using packages shinydashboard, dygraphs, readr, xts, lubridate, tidyr, dplyr on a Windows PC.

Comment: Could it be linked to this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78180725/13203906 .  I don't know  a lot about Linux or Shiny Server.

Comment: @VinceGreg, I don't think that's it, since even when `tzdata-legacy` is split off, `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT+5` is found within the original `tzdata` package. I suspect this is something else (though I don't know yet what that would be).

Answer (score 1):

The correct timezone is `"Etc/GMT+5"`, noting the prepended `Etc/`.

```r
lubridate::with_tz(Sys.time(), tz = "GMT+5")
# Warning in with_tz.default(Sys.time(), tz = "GMT+5") :
#   Unrecognized time zone 'GMT+5'
# [1] "2024-03-21 18:03:07 GMT"
lubridate::with_tz(Sys.time(), tz = "Etc/GMT+5")
# [1] "2024-03-21 18:03:50 -05"
```

Comment: Note that time zones of the form `Etc/GMT±X` have their sign intentionally inverted, because they follow the POSIX `TZ` convention, not the ISO 8601 standard.  A fixed offset of GMT+5 would have a corresponding ID of `Etc/GMT-5`.  (Also, they're mostly for ships at sea.)

Comment: I have no idea what part of the world the OP is intending to reference, it could be plus or minus. The gist of the issue as I see it is that there needs to be the prepended `Etc/`. What makes you say that the OP should reverse the sign in their timezone? GMT-5 "might" refer to the eastern coast of North America, and GMT+5 "might' refer to Pakistan or western Russia. Perhaps it's safe to infer from a username of "Kyle" that it might be a "western-hemisphere" source and therefore your assertion of "wrong sign" might be applicable, but ... that isn't the problem in the question. @MattJohnson-Pint

Comment: You're correct that we don't know much about the OP's time zone other than what they've provided in the question.  However, generally when someone refers to their time zone as "GMT+5", they mean 5 hours ahead of GMT, not 5 hours behind. ISO8601, RFC3339, and local conventions explained ad nauseam on Wikipedia etc., all use that interpretation. It's only POSIX `TZ` environment variable strings that use the opposite (ex., `PST8PDT`).  The IANA fixed offset time zones copy that convention, and explain in even more detail in [the `etcetera` file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/etcetera).

Answer (score 0):

The `tz` parameter passed to `parse_date_time` should follow [the guidance for usage of time zones in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/timezones).

Specifically, you should be using IANA time zone identifiers (aka "Olson" time zones).  You can find a [convenient list of them here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Note that by default on Windows, R will use its own copy of the time zone database, at the location specified by `file.path(R.home("share"), "zoneinfo")`.  This is covered in the R documentation linked above.

With specific regard to a fixed offset of GMT+5, you *could* specify `"Etc/GMT-5"`. Note that the sign is inverted from the usual convention (ie., a `-` indicates the local time is *ahead* of GMT).
However, such fixed offsets are usually reserved for edge cases such as onboard time for ships at sea.

Instead, you should choose a location-based time zone identifier [from the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  For example, `"Asia/Almaty"`.  Location-based identifiers are preferred because *many* time zones alternate between multiple offsets for daylight saving time, and they are *all* subject to potential changes over time.  Using a location-based time zone identifier will ensure that your application can keep up with changes as time zone data is updated on your system.

Comment: Do you know that the OP is not at sea? :-)

Comment: @r2evans - You're right - I don't! :D